# Will any set containing n distinct vector in a n dimensional distinct vectors space be a spanning set?

Tags: linear-algebra

Can any set of vector containing n vector in a n dimensional vector space be used to generate all other possible vectors in that vector space?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.  Consider the set $$\{(1,0),(2,0)\}$$
which is two distinct vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and yet their span is not all of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

If you insist that the set of vectors be linearly independent, then the answer is yes, by the [dimension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces).